# 'tesseract: error while loading shared libraries: libarchive.so.13: python

Tags: heroku, deployment, tesseract, python-tesseract

Error : `pytesseract.pytesseract.TesseractError: (127, 'tesseract: error while loading shared libraries: libarchive.so.13: cannot open shared object file: No such`

My apt file looks like this :

`libgl1 libsm6 libxrender1 libfontconfig1 libarchive-dev libtesseract-dev tesseract-ocr tesseract-ocr-eng`

My requirements file has `pytesseract` mentioned.

I added a buildpack, set the TESSDATA_PREFIX config variable path.

The issue persists.

Comment: This repo might be helpful, it uses `pytesseract` and I deployed it on Heroku https://github.com/techytushar/ocr-date-extractor

Answer (score 5):

I have faced same issue recently. But i fixed by adding the following library in **Aptfile**

- `*libarchive13*`

and then redeployed my app and everything works fine...

Comment: i came across also with this problem and i also need 'heroku-buildpack-apt' to be added to the application build pack (https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt). I'm using heroku stack 22.

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same problem and it seems to be that new heroku stack (heroku-20) has bad compatibility with tesseract. So I just [changed](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-18-stack#using-heroku-18) heroku stack from 20 to 18 using command `heroku stack:set heroku-18`. You can also do it in settings in your dashboard. I also removed unnecessary libraries from `Aptfile` and only left following (German I needed for my purposes so you might not use it):

```
tesseract-ocr 
tesseract-ocr-eng
tesseract-ocr-deu
```

I redeployed my app and everything works!

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my heroku stack from 18 -> 22 and added
`*libarchive13*` in Aptfile which we add in root directory of project & it worked for me .

Downgrading the stack is not a solution as heroku-18 is deprecated & will reach to its end-of-life soon.